# How to connect POWER BI web with AW mysql database?

Tags: amazon-ec2, powerbi

I am new to power bi , i need to connect my AW mysql database with power bi, i did research but did not find any suitable answer can any one help please.?

Comment: Do you want to connect it to aws mysql or Redshift ?

Comment: i want to connect with AWS mysql

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean AWS mysql database?

There is no direct way to connect Power BI yet, you can see on the Power BI Ideas page, the idea is "under review": 
https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6809030-aws-rds-sql-server-data-source

Maybe you can use a BI application from the Amazon Partner list? https://aws.amazon.com/rds/partners/#Business_Intelligence

Comment: that Power BI idea is from 2014. Surely, someone has built a canned approach to this problem by now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power BI Desktop to connect with AWS mysql.
[This article](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/microsoftdynamicscrmsolutions/archive/2015/09/22/mysql-connectivity-to-power-bi-and-schedule-refresh) describe how to connect mysql. After you connect mysql with Power BI Desktop, you can get and manage data.

In addition to it, if you want to see data in Power BI Service (web service), you can use Power BI Gateway with Power BI desktop. These enable your data sync automatically with Power BI Services.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/

thanks,
masa

Comment: You can download and install Power BI Desktop from here.https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/?gated=0&number=1

Comment: The article that you refer uses a locally running MySQL instance. The question is to connect to the MySQL running in AWS. The security related issues will come into picture when trying to access just with IP/DNS name and port which is what is a challenge.

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to get access to AWS mysql database through Power BI desktop. Here is my steps:

1. input remote mysql server IP and mysql database:
   [image: input IP and database name]
2. input remote mysql username and password from Database Tab:
   [image: input username and password]

Then I'm able to get access to the remote database. Hope it helps.