# How to develop a connection for Power BI service to large AWS MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, powerbi

I recently discovered Power BI as part of our Office 365 subscription so am very new to it.

We have a MySQL database with about 5 million rows in AWS. I want to add this as a data source to our Office 365/Power BI service.

How to do this?

I see there is no content pack service that allows me to do this.

According to this SO question and answer, there is no direct way to do this: [How to connect POWER BI web with AW mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125475/how-to-connect-power-bi-web-with-aw-mysql-database).

I also looked at using a Power BI Gateway to achieve this. There are two types: Personal and On-Premises. We don't have any Windows Servers, so this leaves the Personal option: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-personal-gateway/

For Personal, the documentation at that link says "A personal gateway is not required in order to refresh datasets that get data only from an online data source" which is a little confusing given that this seems to be the only option for connecting to my online data source (maybe this document meant to say "from a *supported* online data source"?). It seems that I install this on a local machine in our office, connect to my AWS MySQL database, query/model on my desktop, then upload my results to our Power BI Service for the rest of our company to access. I schedule refreshes using the Personal Gateway. Is this correct? I hope this does not involve the transfer of millions of rows to/from desktop and/or Power BI Service?

p.s. I also considered developing something similar to the content packs that are provided for GitHub, Google Analytics, MailChimp, etc but there doesn't seem to be a "private" way to do these. Doing it this way seems to involve becoming a Certified Azure Developer (even though there is no Azure in this problem) and then making the solution public (which I obviously don't want to do): https://azure.microsoft.com/marketplace/programs/certified/apply/. If there is a way to develop my own "private" solution without the certification and publication process, I would consider that.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? 1. It would be a common use case 2. I described the problem and the question clearly. 3. I explained all the options that I looked at.

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this through Power BI Desktop.  You will need a windows machine to install this on, and it will need the MySQL Connectors installed, ref:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32746679/1787137

Then I would develop and publish your queries, datasets and reports using PBI Desktop.

Finally I would configure PBI Personal Gateway to schedule refresh of the published report datasets.

5m rows is not trivial but quite possible in this scenario.  You will likely only need a selection of your tables and columns, that have analytical value.

Comment: So far, I have been able to connect through Power BI and mysql_connector. However, this appears to involve working with a downloaded copy of the (millions of) records on my desktop. After a couple hours and hung Power BI, I'm trying again.

Comment: Yes that is the architecture.  Power BI has "Direct Query" mode where it generates SQL or MDX on the fly, but not for MySQL.  You need a fairly powerful PC or a commodity server to work with millions of rows in Power BI Desktop.  Note there are file quota limits in PBI Web: currently 1GB for Free, 10GB for Pro.

Comment: Would not the Personal Gateway substitute in this case and allow me to work with the underlying data rather than having to transfer all that data? Or am I misunderstanding what Personal Gateway can do, in this case?

Comment: To take this from a different angle: others have developed content packs for things like GitHub and Google Analytics, which may also involve large amounts of data. Can I develop something like that (except not for the general public, obviously)?

Comment: Re: Personal Gateway, yes you are misunderstanding Personal Gateway.  It essentially just automates the manual steps of Open, Refresh, Publish from PBI Desktop.

Comment: RE: "Private Content Packs", that scenario is not supported AFAIK.